# nginx reverse proxy and paths

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

This is the issue I'm having with this application that we cannot modify:

Example:
I'm trying to set this app so that it goes to:
reverseproxy.com/app1/ which should redirect to:
reverseproxy.com/app1/index.html

However, when the app does a redirect it goes
reverseproxy.com/index.html which throws a 404. (note its missing "app1" in the path)

I've been having a hard time finding a clear answer on this. I assume that it must be something I am missing, here is my current conf:

```
   location /app1 {
      proxy_pass https://applicationserver.com/;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Jon

Comment: You can't. Use subdomain

Comment: Do I understand you right, and the problem is that application itself performs redirect and it ignores your path?

Comment: Yep! We went with your suggestion, just wanted to let you know its working great.